# Suspend / Resume Broken in 16.04 With Unencrypted Drive

Tags: 16.04, suspend, resume

## Problem

After clean installing ubuntu 16.04 and suspending successfully by either closing the laptop lid or pressing the suspend menu button, resume fails and causes the computer to reboot and produce a crash file. Heres the first excerpt. I Have the rest, but I'm not sure what's relevant.

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: This occurred during a previous hibernation, and prevented the system from resuming properly.
Architecture: amd64
CurrentDesktop: Unity
Date: Tue Jul 12 23:33:59 2016
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 16.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume
ExecutableTimestamp: 1463563065
InterpreterPath: /usr/bin/python3.5
Package: linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic 4.4.0-28.47
ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume
ProcCwd: /home/<me>
ProcEnviron:
 SHELL=/bin/bash
 TERM=xterm-256color
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
 LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
```

I was hoping someone could help me understand the cause of this failure. I have a workaround which I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

I have found that I can work around the problem by enabling full disk encryption during the installation process. Im not sure why this is a workaround though. All I know is that I can reproduce the failure and the workaround works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try You use for suspend only terminal command "sudo pm-suspend" I have same problem vhen I use button, but with command is it OK.